# I starting my project using Fused Location provder, but I got an error message while fixing gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am trying to use Fused Location Manager in Android. 
Android said to change gradle file in the project. I changed the file, but it shows the error below. Please help me

[image: error screen]

Comment: Please don't post just screenshots of error messages. Please post them as text.

Answer (score 0):

In dependencies use,
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'

or

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the bottom of the  dependencies.

Then try to clean and rerun.

Comment: I tried both, but error says

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Comment: I think gradle crashes because I am also using GoogleLoginAPI,  is there any ways to use both function? fused location and google login api